# Does "nuget package restore" also transform the web.config?

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild, nuget

I understand that `Nuget Package Restore` is a relatively new feature that combs through my `/packages` folder and adds a `.nuget` folder to my site's root along with an msbuild file, then updates each project in the solution to import the msbuild task.

In addition to this retrieving the appropriate packages from their respective nuget servers and importing the dependencies into the project prior to the app launching, I'm wondering if web.config.transform(s) also get applied?

I assume no. Is that correct?

Theoretically, if the transforms were applied, then I could set varying transformations on different nuget servers in different environments (dev/test/prod) that, when `package restored` from, would dynamically update the web.config with the appropriate environment information.

Is that beyond the scope of `nuget package restore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it's not supported. Package restore is mostly useful for binaries.